Websocket in Golang Fiber framework. Status Code: 426 Upgrade Required
May be I'll not provide you enough needed information. Please ask me to do then.
I get 426 status code but my registered middleware(shown below) doesn't return error, vice versa it "says" that all right.
I have read out that my server should return response with 101 code and with some additional headers but I don't know whether it will help me.
I don't know for what I could hook to get an answer.
*I haven't written my websocket func realization because the code even not get to it.
Middleware registration:
App.Use("/api/v1/claim/ws", middleware.WebsocketUpgrade)
Middleware itself:
func WebsocketUpgrade(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    if websocket.IsWebSocketUpgrade(c) {
        c.Locals("websocket connected", true)

        return c.Next()
    }

    return fiber.ErrUpgradeRequired
}

Registered handler:
claimGroup.Get("/ws/employee/:id", timeout.NewWithContext(handler.WebSocketClaimsCounterHandler(s.serv, s.log, cfg.Server.WS), cfg.Server.AppReadTimeout))

Handler itself:
func WebSocketClaimsCounterHandler(s StaffService, log *logger.Logger, cfg config.WebSocket) fiber.Handler {
    cfgWS := websocket.Config{
        HandshakeTimeout: cfg.HandshakeTimeout,
        Origins:          cfg.Origins,
        ReadBufferSize:   cfg.ReadBufferSize,
        WriteBufferSize:  cfg.WriteBufferSize,
    }

    return websocket.New(func(*websocket.Conn), cfgWS)

I have written down in middleware into response 101 status code, headers "Upgrade: Websocket" and "Connection: Upgrade" but nothing was succeeded.

Please try to province a reproducible example. Ideally just take the example, check that this works for you, then add your changes until it fails. It would also be helpful to know how you are testing this (a 426 response is expected if the request does not include the relevant headers).
